# iPhone twitter request problem

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, twitter

I am currently using the following url http://search.twitter.com/search.json?geocode=_LAT,_LON,50km (where lat and lon are the users co-ordinates) which doesn't require Auth to load local tweets to the device. The problem is I only ever get 15 results. Is there some way of changing this or what is the best way to accomplish a proper timeline of results?

Many thanks

Jules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a parameter rpp with a value up to 100. This will attempt to return 100 results in a single request. https://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/search